# CSS: Grid, Scrollbars and Tooltip issue

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, css-grid

I've been pulling my hairs over a CSS issue that I will try to describe here:

In the following example (https://codesandbox.io/s/jjq4km89y5), you can see a scrollable content (purple background), and a "tooltip" (always showing in this example for practical reasons, red background) that is half hidden by the left panel.

What I need is for both the purple content to be scrollable, AND for the red tooltip to show:

[image: screenshot]

The CSS uses CSS Grid, but the problem is the same if I use flex instead.

The problem seems to lies on the `overflow: auto` statement, (line 59 of styles.css in the code sandbox).

Thanks!!

(to see the example live, please go to https://codesandbox.io/s/jjq4km89y5)

The code, otherwise, can be seen here:

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="nav">Top Nav</div>
      <div class="panel">Left Panel</div>
      <div class="analysis">
        <div>
          <p>Some random content</p>
          <div class="tooltip-trigger">
            A div with a Tooltip (always showing here)
            <div class="tooltip">
              You should be able to see the entirety of this text here,
              going over the Left Nav
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="long-content">
            Some very long content that should make the purple div scroll
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 210px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav"
    "panel analysis";
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.panel {
  grid-area: panel;
  border-right: solid 3px black;
  background-color: grey;
}

.panel > div {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.analysis {
  grid-area: analysis;
  padding: 60px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  background-color: purple;

  /* The problem is here: 
    if set to "auto", then we have a scrollbar but the red tooltip is not visible
    If set to "visible", we get the red tooltip but the scroll is gone
  */
  overflow: auto;
}

.tooltip-trigger {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  border: 5px dashed rebeccapurple;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -200px;
}

.long-content {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 5px dashed darkred;
}
```

You can also see the real-world app and what it does:

[image: Real world app]

The tooltip as you can see will display for all these cells in the table, and needs to be precisely attached to that cell.

The content where the table is needs to be scrollable as well.

Comment: Do you need the red element to overlay only the left panel, or the top nav as well? Moreover, should the red element scroll with the purple element, or stay in it's place When the purple area scrolls?

Comment: the *overflow behaviour* is actually expected... you have to implement the *tooltip* in a different way - ideally a generic tooltip content should be the last in your `body` so that it can *go on top of all other elements*... that's how tooltip plugins do it...

Comment: @jensmtg: Left Panel only is fine (ideally it should be on top of everything, but in my real-world app, it shouldn't need to). The red element should scroll with the purple element, as the div it's attached to (relative to) is the green one, which is part of the purple content.

Comment: @kukkuz: so that's tricky: in my actual app, this tooltip (actually much bigger than a tooltip), is visible on hover when hovering some table cells. Each cell has its own tooltip, so moving that DOM element to the end of the body won't work. I'll add a screenshot of the actual app in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution, or just a nudge in the right direction.

Instead of the tooltip being absolutely-positioned relative to the parent element, make it relative to a more distant ancestor, so it's not affected by the overflow of the purple div.

So, instead of this:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 210px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav"
    "panel analysis";
  height: 100%;
}

.tooltip-trigger {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  border: 5px dashed rebeccapurple;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -200px;
}
```

Try something along these lines:

```
.grid {
  position: relative; /* new */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 210px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav"
    "panel analysis";
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-trigger {
  /* position: relative; */
  background-color: green;
  border: 5px dashed rebeccapurple;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 200px;   /* adjusted */
  left: 60px;   /* adjusted */
}
```

[revised demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3vpkz039p)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Michael_B, unfortunately I can't distance my tooltip from this specific node: as you can see on the "real app" screenshot, the tooltip must be pointing to a specific cell in a table, and I have no way of positioning that correctly if I'm not positioning the tooltip directly relative to that cell.

Comment: Understood. So then, if the tooltip is absolutely-positioned relative to the same container that is overflowing, keeping the tooltip in a fixed position is not possible, at least not with this method.

Comment: I was afraid it might be the case. It's odd because I can't see any technical reason browsers shouldn't be able to do that. I'll probably have to resort to using JavaScript, fixed positioning and tracking the position of the cell I need to attach the tooltip to. Hacky, but if there's no other way...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a hack, but I think it can be made to work without too bad side effects: Instead of arranging the `left panel` and `analysis` as sibling DOM-nodes, you could layer `analysis` inside and over `left panel`.
With some tweaking to adjust placement of content you could make it look like they are side by side. Instead of scrolling `analysis`, with a static `left panel`, you can scroll `left panel` and make the `left panel` content absolutely positioned.

I made a quick and dirty implementation to demonstrate the mechanics:

[Revised code example](https://l9lwlxnpr9.codesandbox.io/)

Markup:

```
<div className="panel">
  <div className="panelContent">Left Panel</div>
  <div className="panelSpacer" />
  <div className="analysis">
    <div>
      <p>Some random content</p>
      <div className="tooltip-trigger">
        A div with a Tooltip (always showing here)
        <div className="tooltip">
          You should be able to see the entirety of this text here,
          going over the Left Nav
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="long-content">
        Some very long content that should make the purple div scroll
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
  grid-area: panel;
  border-right: solid 3px black;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
}

.panelSpacer {
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.panelContent {
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

.panel > div {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.analysis {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 210px);
  padding: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;

  /* The problem is here: 
    if set to "auto", then we have a scrollbar but the red tooltip is not visible
    If set to "visible", we get the red tooltip but the scroll is gone
  */
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very great idea! Very "outside-the-box", I love it, and it could indeed well be the solution to my problem. I'll try and implement it now, and will accept the answer if it works. Thank you!!